# Is data retrieved from /events dependent on the access token used to retrieve it?

Tags: support, api-v2, events

This may seem like a bit of an unusual question at first but I'll try to explain where it's coming from. My PHP wrapper (Stack.PHP) offers a caching class that follows the guidelines in the API docs for each method (caching data from `/sites` for a minimum of 24 hours, etc.). `/events` requires authentication and therefore must be authorized by a *specific* user.

Does the data retrieved differ depending on the user authorizing the application? I'm guessing that it doesn't but if it *does* then my PHP wrapper probably shouldn't be caching the data.

Perhaps a better way of wording the question is like this: can data retrieved through the `/events` method be shared publicly or should it only be displayed to the user that granted access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the same data is returned for a call to `/events` regardless of the access token used.

This may change in a future release, but it's guaranteed for v2.0.